# urlopen error [errno 111] connection refused

Tags: android, python, json, sl4a

I am doing python exercise with a book 'headfirst python'
and making android app by using python and sl4a
my code is

```
import android
import json
import time

from urllib import urlencode
from urllib2 import urlopen

hello_msg     = "Welcome to Coach Kelly's Timing App"
list_title    = 'Here is your list of athletes:'
quit_msg      = "Quitting Coach Kelly's App."
web_server    = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080'
get_names_cgi = '/cgi-bin/generate_name.py'

def send_to_server(url, post_data=None):
    if post_data:
        page = urlopen(url, urlencode(post_data))
    else:
        page = urlopen(url)
    return(page.read().decode("utf8"))

app = android.Android()

def status_update(msg, how_long=2):
    app.makeToast(msg)
    time.sleep(how_long)

status_update(hello_msg)

athlete_names = sorted(json.loads(send_to_server(web_server + get_names_cgi)))
app.dialogCreateAlert(list_title)
app.dialogSetSingleChoiceItems(athlete_names)
app.dialogSetPositiveButtonText('Select')
app.dialogSetNegativeButtonText('Quit')
app.dialogShow()
resp = app.dialogGetResponse().result

status_update(quit_msg)
```

this is my code and the result is 
[image]

what is the problem???
I can not figure out what the problem is...

Comment: Did you run webserver (at port 8080) in the system?

Comment: yes i ran local host 8080

Comment: Did you run the webserver at android? If so, are you running any firewall program at android?

Comment: If you are running the server at your desktop/server (not in the android), you should adjust `web_server    = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080'` line accordingly.

Comment: can please try to run it as http://10.0.2.2:8080

Comment: Yes!! it works!! thank you Osama Espil!!! and falsetru too!

Comment: @OsamaEspil can you explain the reason?

Comment: can you mark it as right so people can refer to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 10.0.2.2:8080

because If you are running both server and emulator in you computer 127.0.0.1:(port) the local IP will refer to the emulator then you need another local IP for the server which will be automatically The 10.0.2.2

hope i clearified it well, glad i helped

Answer (score 0):

Having followed @Coderji 's solution, I was finally able to solve this problem albeit with a different IP address; since the suggested 10.0.2.2 didn't work for me.
What worked for me was to access a terminal, ipconfig, and then used any of the provided ipv4 addresses provided by cmd (all of them seemed to work). Cheers.